Memory leak while use of spdlog
I use spdlog c++ library.
I observe memory leak while call to logger methods
What is wrong in the following code that creates logger?
static  std::shared_ptr<class spdlog::logger> CombinedLogger;
static  std::vector<spdlog::sink_ptr> Sinks;

bool CreateLogger(const char *loggerName, const char* logName, std::chrono::seconds interval, const char* logFormat)
{
    
    Sinks.push_back(std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::stdout_color_sink_mt>());
    Sinks.push_back(std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::basic_file_sink_mt>(logName)); 
    CombinedLogger = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>(loggerName, begin(Sinks), end(Sinks));

    CombinedLogger->flush_on(spdlog::level::err);
    spdlog::flush_every(interval);
    CombinedLogger->set_pattern(logFormat);

    spdlog::register_logger(CombinedLogger);
    return true;
}

I create and use logger as following:
Logger::CreateLogger(name, logName, std::chrono::seconds(LogFlushTimeSec), "%Y-%m-%d | %H:%M:%S.%f| %n| %^%-10l%$|  %v");
std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> logging = spdlog::get(LoggerName);

logging->info("Execution Time and Date:  {} ", std::ctime(&startTime));

Each call to logging methods (info, debug and so on) causes memory leak.

A side note: using global/static variables is usually an indication for poorl design. You can consider to have CreateLogger return the logger instance, and store it in e.g. a member.

Are you sure it's actually a leak? How do you know? Do you build and run with a compiler sanitizer? Do you use a memory debugger and leak detector like Valgrind?

by the way, I'd strongly discourage use of std::ctime in multi-threaded contexts (like yours!) There's so many better ways to handle times in std::chrono. ctime is even marked POSIX-obsolete.

I suspect there is a leak in the logging methods.

You should not make your logger a shared_ptr. Create ONE instance in main, and then use dependency injection to use the logger throught your code. There's even better ways to fully decouple logging from the rest of your code.  Create an abstract baseclass (or multiple) with methods you can call when you want something logged. e.g. virtual void ReportXYZHappened() then create an instance that will forward to speedlog and use dependency injection to inject your own interface into the code that needs to log.
